# Cycling Event Listeners vs many Listeners

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some work with a program that has quite a lot to click, however somethings only need to be clicked when say their parent has been clicked on and is active. Now there are three ways as I see it to approach this.

1. Many event handlers
2. Constantly Create and Destroy them
3. Have one top-level handler and read the Event for what child even occurred on (event.target)

The reason three is not the most obvious choice for me is that children of what I clicked would be `event.target` and `object.parentNode` would need to repeatedly run to see what element was in-fact available for clicking; I hear DOM api's are expensive.

I'm interested to know how expensive each method is relative to each other and what is accepted practice in something like that. Number of listeners is in the hundreds range, it's a dynamic application with modest DOM mutation.

**EDIT:** For clarification this question is about DIV's and attaching event handlers to them.

Comment: Do you have  jquery or similar available?

Comment: No, I use pure. I like to have a low-level code as I can, staves off dependency mentally.

Comment: Nothing wrong with either - but it helps inform the answers :)

Comment: What type of events? 3. is obvious choice for clicks for example.

Comment: Yeh, clicks, but again that targets the most inner child when they may or may not be available for clicking. I'd have to propagate `.parentNode` to find parent that was actually the thing that needed to be clicked. The reason 1 is even an option is for the purpose of bubbling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using buttons or similar you can enable and disable them. They usually have a different appearance too so the user can know not to click on a disabled button.

If you aren't using buttons, you can add or remove a class called disabled. When the element is clicked, the listener can check its class and if it has a class of "disabled", have it do nothing. Otherwise, have it do what it does.

The addition and removal of the class can also be used to modify the appearance of the element, making it look disabled (similar to how buttons and inputs change appearance when disabled).

Simple has/add/removeClass functions:

```
var util = {dom:{}};

util.trim = function(s) {
  return s.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}

util.dom.hasClassName = function(el, cName) {
    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)');
    return el && re.test(el.className);
}

util.dom.addClassName = function(el, cName) {
    if (!util.dom.hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        el.className = util.trim(el.className + ' ' + cName);
    }
}

util.dom.removeClassName = function(el, cName) {
    if (util.dom.hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)','g');
        el.className = util.trim(el.className.replace(re, ''));
    }
}
```

A simple example:

```
<script>

function toggle(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);

  if (!el) return;

  if (util.dom.hasClassName(el, 'disabled')) {
    util.dom.removeClassName(el, 'disabled')
  } else {
    util.dom.addClassName(el, 'disabled')
  }
}

function doStuff(el) {
  if (util.dom.hasClassName(el, 'disabled')) return;
  alert('I\'m alive!');
}

</script>

<button id="b0" onclick="doStuff(this);">button 0</button>
<button onclick="toggle('b0')">change b0</button>
```

Alternatively the disabled property could be set to true or false.

You can also maintain state independantly of the elements, so when an element is clicked on it knows what to do based on the state if its child or parent elements (or whatever).

Comment: Well, what I'm working with doesn't really involve buttons, its specific to event listeners. What I'm looking for is the general comparison to the methods I mentioned.

Comment: Buttons are just an example, you can use any type of element, any event and whatever logic you want. I would prefer to have a single listener and do the logic (including making an element enabled or disabled) in a program, but that's just me. I don't like the idea of constantly adding and removing listeners, it seems inefficient to me.